# declaring multiple variable with random values

Tags: python

```
import random

a = random.randint(0,7)
b = random.randint(0,7)
c = random.randint(0,7)
d = random.randint(0,7)
...
```

How can I be more efficient at declaring these variables as I want them to be random?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Maybe you should be using a list and a loop, rather than declaring multiple variables.

Comment: Why not an array?

Comment: I am not using arrays because I need only 2 variables, but I asked this just out of curiosity!

Answer (score 4):

```
x, y, z = (random.randint(0, 7) for x in range(3))
```

This generates a tuple of 3 random integers and assigns them to x, y, and z.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to save some typing, you can use a generator

```
In [2]: (a,b,c,d) = (random.randint(0,7) for x in range(4))

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: b
Out[4]: 7
```

Now, if you also want the variables to be created dynamically, you can use `__dict__`:

```
In [21]: import __main__

In [22]: for v in range (ord('a'), ord('z')):
    ...:     __main__.__dict__[chr(v)] = random.randint (0,7)

In [25]: x
Out[25]: 5

In [26]: y
Out[26]: 3

In [27]: q
Out[27]: 2
```

If that's the case, though, I'd rather use an actual dict for storing the values, with letters as keys, instead of creating variables for them.

And, of course, use `self.__dict__` instead of `__main__` if you're using classes.